# Mix Shader Difference?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

What is the difference between putting a diffuse shader 1st and then a glossy shader 2nd into a mixed shader or a glossy shader 1st and then diffuse shader 2nd in blender cycles?

Comment: Nothing, the difference is driven by the `Factor` input

Answer (score 1):

It should depend on the "factor" of the mix, [citing the manual](http://www.blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/types/color/mix.htm):
"Fac
    The amount of mixing of the bottom socket is selected by the Factor input field (Fac:). A factor of zero does not use the bottom socket, whereas a value of 1.0 makes full use. In Mix mode, 0.5 is an even mix between the two, but in Add mode, 0.5 means that only half of the second socket’s influence will be applied."